# how to use the Box-Cox power transformation in R

Tags: r, regression, transformation

I need to transform some data into a 'normal shape' and I read that Box-Cox can identify the exponent to use to transform the data.

For what I understood

```
car::boxCoxVariable(y)
```

is used for response variables in linear models, and

```
MASS::boxcox(object)
```

for a formula or fitted model object. So, because my data are the variable of a dataframe, the only function I found I could use is:

```
car::powerTransform(dataframe$variable, family="bcPower")
```

Is that correct? Or am I missing something?

The second question is about what to do after I obtain the

```
Estimated transformation parameters
dataframe$variable
0.6394806
```

Should I simply multiply the *variable* by this value?
I did so:

```
aaa = 0.6394806
dataframe$variable2 = (dataframe$variable)*aaa
```

and then I run the shapiro-wilks test for normality, but again my data don't seem to follow a normal distribution:

```
shapiro.test(dataframe$variable2)
data:  dataframe$variable2
W = 0.97508, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

Comment: I found to be a good documentation with clear R code and examples (and also for other transformations) the chapter [Transforming Data](https://rcompanion.org/handbook/I_12.html) in the handbook [Summary and Analysis of Extension Program Evaluation in R](https://rcompanion.org/handbook/)

Comment: @Valentin very good explanation provided in the book mentioned. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 41):

Box and Cox (1964) suggested a family of transformations designed to reduce nonnormality of the **errors** in a linear model. In turns out that in doing this, it often reduces non-linearity as well.

Here is a nice summary of the original work and all the work that's been done since: http://www.ime.usp.br/~abe/lista/pdfm9cJKUmFZp.pdf

You will notice, however, that the log-likelihood function governing the selection of the lambda power transform is dependent on the residual sum of squares of an underlying model (no LaTeX on SO -- see the reference), so no transformation can be applied without a model.

A typical application is as follows:

```
library(MASS)

# generate some data
set.seed(1)
n <- 100
x <- runif(n, 1, 5)
y <- x^3 + rnorm(n)

# run a linear model
m <- lm(y ~ x)

# run the box-cox transformation
bc <- boxcox(y ~ x)
```

[image]

```
(lambda <- bc$x[which.max(bc$y)])
[1] 0.4242424

powerTransform <- function(y, lambda1, lambda2 = NULL, method = "boxcox") {

  boxcoxTrans <- function(x, lam1, lam2 = NULL) {

    # if we set lambda2 to zero, it becomes the one parameter transformation
    lam2 <- ifelse(is.null(lam2), 0, lam2)

    if (lam1 == 0L) {
      log(y + lam2)
    } else {
      (((y + lam2)^lam1) - 1) / lam1
    }
  }

  switch(method
         , boxcox = boxcoxTrans(y, lambda1, lambda2)
         , tukey = y^lambda1
  )
}


# re-run with transformation
mnew <- lm(powerTransform(y, lambda) ~ x)

# QQ-plot
op <- par(pty = "s", mfrow = c(1, 2))
qqnorm(m$residuals); qqline(m$residuals)
qqnorm(mnew$residuals); qqline(mnew$residuals)
par(op)
```

[image]

As you can see this is no magic bullet -- only some data can be effectively transformed (usually a lambda less than -2 or greater than 2 is a sign you should not be using the method). As with any statistical method, use with caution before implementing.

To use the two parameter Box-Cox transformation, use the `geoR` package to find the lambdas:

```
library("geoR")
bc2 <- boxcoxfit(x, y, lambda2 = TRUE)

lambda1 <- bc2$lambda[1]
lambda2 <- bc2$lambda[2]
```

EDITS: Conflation of Tukey and Box-Cox implementation as pointed out by @Yui-Shiuan fixed.

Comment: You might point out that it's possible to get the same answer using `MASS` by using the model `lm(y ~ 1)` (in this case, `bc <- boxcox(variable ~ 1, data=dataframe)`).  `powerTransform()` gives the "right" lambda, but the data have things going on that make it impossible to force normality using just Box-Cox.

Comment: Great answer! May I ask why you emphasized "errors" in the beginning of your answer? Is this because one is to transform the response variable (e.g. y in y ~ x_1 + x_2) and not the covariates (x_1 or x_2), or can one transform the covariates as well?

Answer (score 23):

According to the Box-cox transformation formula in the paper *Box,George E. P.; Cox,D.R.(1964). "An analysis of transformations"*, I think **mlegge's post might need to be slightly edited.The transformed y should be (y^(lambda)-1)/lambda instead of y^(lambda).** (Actually, y^(lambda) is called Tukey transformation, which is another distinct transformation formula.)

So, the code should be:

```
(trans <- bc$x[which.max(bc$y)])
[1] 0.4242424
# re-run with transformation
mnew <- lm(((y^trans-1)/trans) ~ x) # Instead of mnew <- lm(y^trans ~ x)
```

#### More information

- Correct implementation of Box-Cox transformation formula by boxcox() in R:
  https://www.r-bloggers.com/on-box-cox-transform-in-regression-models/
- A great comparison between Box-Cox transformation and Tukey transformation. http://onlinestatbook.com/2/transformations/box-cox.html
- One could also find the Box-Cox transformation formula on Wikipedia:
  en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_transform#Box.E2.80.93Cox_transformation

Please correct me if I misunderstood it.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out (with excellent documentation!). I've updated my answer to try to address this

Answer (score 5):

If I want tranfer only the response variable y instead of a linear model with x specified, eg I wanna transfer/normalize a list of data, I can take 1 for x, then the object becomes a linear model:

```
library(MASS)
y = rf(500,30,30)
hist(y,breaks = 12)
result = boxcox(y~1, lambda = seq(-5,5,0.5))
mylambda = result$x[which.max(result$y)]
mylambda
y2 = (y^mylambda-1)/mylambda
hist(y2)
```

Comment: had 4 different variables with all 4 histograms showing nonnormal distribution, this solution helped me to bring them to a normal distribution individually.

Answer (score 1):

Applying the BoxCox transformation to data, without the need of any underlying model, can be done currently using the package [geoR](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/geoR/versions/1.3-0/topics/BoxCox). Specifically, you can use the function *boxcoxfit*() for finding the best parameter and then predict the transformed variables using the function *BCtransform*().