# Linear Box Cox Transformation for different parameters for dependent variable/ and independent vaiable

Tags: linear-regression, box, cox-regression, data-transform

I've been stuck on this for quite some time. Is there a command in R that will create a Box Cox Linear transformation that has a different a parameter for my independent variable and dependent variable?

```
chicago.reg <- lm(data = Chichagodata, sprice ~ nrooms + lvarea + hage + lsize + ptaxes + sspend + mspend +
                medinc + dfcl + particle + sulfur+pctwht+ dfni +aircon+ garage+ nbath + cook+ohare)
```

Note that I do not want to transform my variables pctwht, dfni, aircon, garage, nbath, cook,and ohare as they are dummy variables.

Thank you if you can provide me insight on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look into `coxBox` and `boxcox` functions. The former allow to transform individual variables/lists, while the latter works on `lm` (or `aov`) objects. In addition you might want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33999512/how-to-use-the-box-cox-power-transformation-in-r) and [this](https://www.r-bloggers.com/on-box-cox-transform-in-regression-models/) posts...