# Convert raw data to Gaussian (normal) using qqplot leads to different normal values for same raw data value

Tags: r, transform, gaussian

I want to convert raw data to Gaussian (mean=0, std =1) using qqnorm function. What I realize though, is that for the same raw values, I get different Gaussian value. Eg:

```
mydata = c(2.4,       3.7,       2.1,       3,         1.6,       2.5,       2.9, 2.9 )
myquant = qqnorm(mydata)
myquant
          -0.4727891  1.4342002 -0.8524950  0.8524950 -1.4342002 -0.1525060  0.1525060  0.4727891
```

Moreover, I have used the following code to transform data into normal one:

```
for (i in 1:ncol(sampledataSubGaus) ) {
  
  
  sampledataSubGaus[,i] <- qqnorm( as.matrix(sampledataSub[,i]) )$x
  
}
```

where I face the same issue again.
Is there an explanation for that? For your information, I have used another function called score.transform, which behaves properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you mean by "convert" your data to N(0,1) using `qqnorm`.  The `qqnorm()` function returns `x`, which are the normal quantiles associated with the corresponding quantiles from your data.  The guts of `qqnorm()` are doing the following:

```r
mydata = c(2.4,3.7,2.1,3,1.6,2.5,2.9, 2.9 )
y <- mydata  
n <- length(y)
x <- qnorm(ppoints(n))[order(order(y))]
plot(x,y)
```

[image]

If you took a subset of these values, you would get different values of `x`, because it would be using a different number of points to generate the normal quantiles (i.e., the values of `ppoints(n)` would be different).

I could be wrong, but I have never heard of someone using `qqnorm()` to transform data - it is a diagnostic for normality, but not a remedy.  Something like a [Box-Cox transformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33999512/how-to-use-the-box-cox-power-transformation-in-r) could, under the right circumstances, help transform a skewed variable into something that had a more normal distribution.